# How to query multiple SUMs into multiple columns of the same SQL query in iReport?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport

Is this efficient? How could it be improved?

I was trying to get data from one set of columns into two sets of columns according to a condition. All the methods I tried ended up with multiple rows.

This is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002639/how-to-query-multiple-sums-of-the-same-item-using-sql-in-ireport) but a bit more complicated.

Here's what I did:
(Because this is for iReport/JasperReports, it would have been a major hassle to use multiple queries.) Basically we want to get the statistics for living friendly and non-friendly soldiers from two tables for an army war game exercise.

```
SELECT 
   army.army_key UNIT_NUM,
   COUNT( case when soldier.type_id = 1 then 1 else NULL end ) AS friendCount, 
   SUM( case when soldier.type_id = 1 then soldier.achievement else 0 end ) AS friendAmount, 
   COUNT( case when soldier.type_id = 2 then 1 else NULL end ) AS enemyCount, 
   SUM( case when soldier.type_id = 2 then soldier.achievement else 0 end ) AS enemyAmount
   FROM soldier, army
   WHERE soldier.army_key = army.army_key 
      AND army.wargame_id = $P{GAME_ID} 
      AND soldier.dead is null 
   GROUP BY army.army_key
   ORDER BY UNIT_NUM ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me.  No Cartesian products, and no violations of Single-Value rule.

Other generic performance advice applies.  Get a report from the optimizer to make sure you're using indexes properly.

Consider if compound indexes would help (e.g. army: `wargame_id`, `army_key`).

Consider covering indexes (e.g. soldier: `army_key`, `dead`, `type_id`, `achievement`).